# Firebase Flutter error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

Tags: firebase, flutter, validation, firebase-authentication

im having trouble with authentication on Firebase.

there is a [login screen that asks for the number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGgve.jpg), then on the next button press it goes to the [OTP screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsWSY.jpg) that results in authenticating the user.

But after the verification number is typed, it doesnt authenticate and says [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR7rL.png)

this is the code that i use to verify the user

```
  final String PhoneNumber; //globally declared

_verifyPhone() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: widget.PhoneNumber,
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .signInWithCredential(credential)
              .then((value) async {
            if (value.user != null) {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                      EmailScreen(PhoneNumber: widget.PhoneNumber),
                ),
              );
            }
          });
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
          print(e.message);
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationID, int resendToken) {
          setState(() {
            _verificationCode = verificationID;
          });
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationID) {
          setState(() {
            _verificationCode = verificationID;
          });
        },
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 60));
  }
```

and this is the OnSubmit function of the PinEntryTextField

```
    PinEntryTextField(
          fields: 6,
          showFieldAsBox: true,
          onSubmit: (String pin) async {
            try {
              await FirebaseAuth.instance
                  .signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                      verificationId: _verificationCode, smsCode: pin))
                  .then((value) async {
                if (value.user != null) {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => EmailScreen(
                                PhoneNumber: widget.PhoneNumber,
                              )));
                }
              });
            } catch (e) {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              print(e);
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text("Failed because $e"),
              ));
            }
          },
        ),
```

Now it works sometimes, but sometimes it doesn't, that's the weird thing.

any help would be appreciated..

thanks

Comment: In the future when you have enough rep, be sure to include images in the question. Links sometimes break and if that happens we won't know what those images were, which would make the question unclear and possibly unusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i had to wait a few seconds until the SMS code "arrives"..
Because i was using a test phone number

Silly me

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if the phone number is not going to be null. In my case phone number is going null so this error was come.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.